# what is the word for things that a method can deliver?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> I have reviewed individual methods about their pros and cons,
>   corresponding scope conditions, **deliverables**, and their applications
>   in Europe.

Can deliverables be used here to refer to things a method can bring to? For example, I use the method of in-situ measurement to test air quality, and I will get concentrations of PM2.5, CO2, etc. I don't want to use the word **results**, because I think results refer to exact value/readings, which is not the focus.

Comment: ***deliverables*** is something of a jargon buzzword in the IT industry, where it usually means *things which can be easily identified **by the customer*** as having been received *especially as a product of a development process*. The customer can see that development is progressing, if he can see that his IT system is significantly better than it was before the most recent "incremental upgrade". There will often be agreed time-based targets for certain features to be delivered, with the customer being expected to "sign off / accept" various "deliverables" soon after each incremental upgrade.

Comment: ahhh, I see. thank you. Then deliverables is not the word....Do you have any word recommendations for my case?

Comment: I don't know your *exact* context (*what* you're talking about, *who* you're saying it to, *what* you mean, etc.), so I can't say what word might be best. I explained how ***deliverables*** is usually used (you could look at [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22deliverables%22) for written examples), but I don't know if it suits your context (and I don't know ***why*** you say it's "not the word" for you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Deliverable** (noun)

Something that can be provided or achieved as a result of a process:

> What are the project deliverables?
>
> Tell them what the deliverables are and what they are going to be charged.

**Deliverable** (adjective)

Able to be delivered, achieved, or produced:

> The goods must be in a deliverable state at the time of the contract.
>
> The goods were not in a deliverable state.

so

> Can deliverables be used here to refer to things a method can bring
>   to?

Yes, it is!